# Attaching JQuery delegate for more than one event to a handler

Tags: jquery

I read that the new delegate method can attach more than one event to a handler however I have not see this in practice. Would anyone type a code for this please.

I tried:

```
$("body").delegate("input", "mouseup", "mouseover", function() {
            $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
        });
```

and it appended the paragraph only on mouseup. I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a space delimiter for events like this:

```
$("body").delegate("input", "mouseup mouseover", function() {
   $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
});
```

You probably meant to select `<input>` elements, I changed this above, correct me if you meant otherwise.

Alternatively, use `.bind()` like this:

```
$("body input").bind("mouseup mouseover", function() {
   $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
});
```

I find this easier to read, but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: (types || "").split is not a function

Comment: @XGreen - Fixed, forgot you're not binding, which is simpler in this case, I'll add an example

Answer (score 0):

The reference **[.delegate() | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** says about second parameter:

A string containing **one or more space-separated JavaScript event types**, such as "click" or "keydown," or custom event names.

Therefore, in your case:

```
$("body").delegate("input", "mouseup mouseover", function() {
            $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph!</p>");
        });
```